# PHP How I can selected near word with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string like:

```
$str = "Hello, I'm a beautiful, string. How are you?";
```

And I want to get the next word of "beautiful". I mean, I want to get "string".
I think this is better do it with pre_match in opposite to do with iterator arrays and compare each word... (commas, dots and slashes must be omitted).
I don't know anything about it... and if it is possible.

Comment: is the thing you want always going to be a string after `beautiful,` up until the first occurrence of a `.`?  Basically always what is in the parenthesis is going to be just characters? Or is it going to have numbers or special characters? `$str = "Hello, I'm a beautiful, (string). How are you?";`

Comment: @Jay: It doesn't matter if string ending with a dot... the only think that I know is his before word. For example in "Hello, I'm the second foo for other example"; I want to get the str after to 'second' (for example) and, I hope to get the str "foo"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
\bbeautiful\b\W*\b(\w+)\b
```

Which is something like:

- Match your word with word boundaries on both sides
- Match any number of non-word characters
- Match the next word (with word boundaries on both sides)

[An example](http://regex101.com/r/yW4zB1/2).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/tG9cS4/1):

```
~beautiful[^a-zA-Z\d.]*([a-zA-Z\d]+)~
```

E.g. in PHP:

```
preg_match('~beautiful[^a-zA-Z\d.]*([a-zA-Z\d]+)~', $str, $results);
echo $results[1]; // string
```

Broken down:

```
~ 
    beautiful        // match "beautiful literally
    [^a-zA-Z\d]*     // don't match any letters or digits zero or more (catch punctuation etc)
    (                // open capture group
        [a-zA-Z\d]+  // match letters or numbers at least once
    )                // close capture group (stops at first occurence that 
~                    //   doesn't match above
```